# How can I get xticklabel and yticklabel bold when activating LaTeX text rendering with Times New Roman font in Python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to generate a figure with LaTeX text rendering activated. I want to use Time New Roman font for all the texts in the figure (including the mathematical texts) and I encounter some problems when trying to make the xticklabel and yticklable bold, here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc,rcParams
from pylab import *

tmpData = np.random.random( 100 )

rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.serif": ["Times"],
    'font.weight': 'bold'})
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{fontspec} \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}']

#create figure
f = figure(figsize=(10,10))

ax = gca()

plot(np.arange(100), tmpData, label=r'\textbf{Line 1}', linewidth=2)

ylabel(r'\textbf{Y-AXIS}', fontsize=20)
xlabel(r'\textbf{X-AXIS}', fontsize=20)

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=20)

legend()
```

I understand that the problem may due to the fact that the xticklabels on the x axis should really be interpreted as mathematical texts, but I am still struggling with this...
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code above `legend()`

```
 ylabs = [ f"{ilab:<.1f}" for ilab in ax.get_yticks()]
 xlabs = [ f"{ilab:<.0f}" for ilab in ax.get_xticks()]
 ax.set_yticklabels(ylabs, weight='bold', size=20)
 ax.set_xticklabels(xlabs, weight='bold', size=20)
```

output is here.[image]

Comment: Hi @Yupeng, thanks for your reply, may I ask how I can change the latex compiler when using matplotlib? I am getting an error message as: `The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX`. I guess changing it in my local TeX IDE won't help? If possible, could you please share the full script for this? Thanks in advance!